# Is there a way to use a matcher like 'Verify' in rspec?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, matcher

So far I'm using 'expect' in my test framework which will stop the execution when it meets a fail condition. I want something like, the execution should happen even if it meets the fail condition. I could see that there is a matcher called 'Verify' in rspec where I need to inherit 'Test::Unit::TestCase' class, but my issue is that, I need the matcher in my spec file which is not written under a ruby class.

Comment: I wonder why someone could need to a test that proceeds after a failure...Just curious.

Comment: @microspino Let's say it fails in some numbers verification but I want the suite to run completely so as to check whether any other inequalities are present in the workflow. It will help in fixing all the glitches in one shot as it unearths everything in one round of execution. But yea, it has it's own pros and cons.

Comment: If you are comparing objects like a hash, array you can use match/eq and it will show you the differences, if you have several expects in one call you can split them into multiple tests by putting one expect call in each `it` block, keep in mind that adds to test time.

Comment: It's not only about getting the differences but to let the suite do the execution even if it meets the fail condition. And, yea I have used 'match' and 'eq' matchers in my test suite. Since, every matcher here accompanies with 'expect', it jus stops the execution once the fail condition meets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this with RSpec, out of the box.
Because Rspec is designed to test small, isolated logics.

On failure, Rspec matchers raise Error, So what you can do is to wrap the matchers in a rescue block.
To satisfy your need, you could write a wrapper like this:

```
def report_last(&block)
  begin
    yield
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Failure: #{e}"
  end
end
```

In your test case:

```
describe Calculator do
  it “should add 2 numbers” do
    report_last do
      expect(described_class.new(2, 3).sum)to eq(5)
    end
  end
end
```